# CSS Calc() using two pixel amounts to get a percentage

Tags: html, css, calc

I want to do basic calculations in CSS to get a responsive layout.

Is it possible to get a % output from a basic equation, e.g. can I get the width in the below example to be set to 72%?

```
    width: calc(540px / 750px);
```

This would make the audit trail in my work easier to follow as a number of percentages will be odd, e.g. 13.33333333% etc.

Thanks

Comment: Why not just put `72%`, literally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass a `%` unit, than the desired *integer* values

```css
div{
  background:red;
  height:24px;
  width: calc(100% * (540 / 750));               /* 72% */
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: 4 sec ... ouch :) ... +1

Comment: Great, thanks... Obviously need to brush up my css ;)